# WordPress Theme Installation Error 'Are you sure you want to do this? Try Again'

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

I am trying to install a premium WordPress theme (size=13.4mb) on my blog, hosted by Microsoft Azure. When I try to install the theme, I am getting the following after 100% of uploading the theme:

Are you sure you want to do this? Try again
I have been seeking for a solution for hours now. I read about changing these setting:

```
max_execution_time 100
memory_limit 256M
post_max_size 32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
```

How do I change these setting on the Azure platform or is there somewhere a description where this been described step by step about how and where to change the setting in the PHP files?

Please show me how to navigate to the solution to be able to upload themes?

Answer (score 1):

By default on Azure, the `upload_max_filesize` is set to 8M, we can change the built-in PHP configurations to enlarge it.

Here are the steps:

1, Add a .user.ini file to your root directory.

2, Add configuration settings to the .user.ini file using the same syntax you would use in a php.ini file. With your demand, your .user.ini file would contain this text:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 300
```

3, Deploy your web app.

4, Restart the web app.

You can read [official guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations) for more information.

By the way, we can use FTP tool to connect your Azure Web sites server to create and modify the custom configuration file instead of redeploying the project.

The default root directory is *`D:\home\site\wwwroot`*.

Answer (score 0):

These settings can be changed in your php.ini file that is hosted by your hosting company. I am not familiar with Asure platform.

However, the error you are getting seems too generic.

The theme you downloaded, are you sure you uploaded the right file. Some themes are a zip file with other files in them and you have to first unzip and then there will be a wordpress theme upload ready zip file that you upload. Look inside the uploading zip file to ensure the folder structure is right.

Also, if you purchased the theme i am sure you can get support from the theme developers.